# Retrieving cookies with javascript XMLHTTPReq

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Just wondering if it's possible to use an XMLHTTPReq to login to a website, and store the cookie. Specifically I'm after the PHPSessionID from the website I am logging into.

I then want to pass this cookie into another request to submit a form.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Cheers,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to get your own site's cookies from `document.cookie`.  In the AJAX callback, use [a library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to parse the value and read the cookie you're looking for.

Of course, if the [server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly) sets the cookie [`HttpOnly`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) (which it *should* be doing), it won't be available in `document.cookie`.

At this pont, you need to reevaluate what you're doing:

- If the form points to your website, your server script would have access to the cookie anyway.
- If you're sending the user's session ID to another domain, why?  This is a huge red flag that screams security problem.

---

If you're logging in to another site, then no – the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from accessing another site's cookies.

---

**Edit**: Since this is for your own use, you can do this in a way you're not limited by the browser's origin restrictions.  Some thoughts:

- You could make a Chrome extension.  Extensions [aren't subject to origin restrictions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html), and the development model and API is pretty much the same as what you'd do on a regular web page.
- You could use [Node](http://nodejs.org/), which has no restrictions.  You'd be able to invoke your script from the command line, but the [API](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) is going to be slightly different that what you'd use in a web page.
- Use your language and framework of choice to `POST` to the login page, get the `Set-Cookie` header in the response, and use it to send a `Cookie` header in another `POST` to the form target.

Comment: The site I want to send the cookie to is the same one as the one that set it though...

Comment: Sorry. 
I don't actually own the website I am doing this on, so I can't access it there.
What I'm basically trying to do is make a script that will log me onto the 3rd party website, then once logged in, submit a form on my behalf on that website.

Comment: In that case, my original answer was correct.  If you *were* able to accomplish this, the 3rd party site has a major security hole.  It's very much **by design** that a script on one origin has no access to other origins.  Without that protection, I could put a script on my site that might--for example--tell your bank to send me all your money.  (However, this is something you could do from higher-privileged script, such as an [extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html).)

Comment: You could only do that if you had my bank login...
I basically want to simulate myself logging into the website, typing something into the form, and submitting it.
If a httpreq isn't the best way to do this, what else could you suggest?

Comment: If there were no same-origin policy, I could in fact tell your bank to send me all your money.  Consider what would happen if you were *already* logged in to your bank when you browsed to my malicious site.  With the ability to access other sites' cookies -- or even just to send an XHR to your bank (which would intrinsically include your login/session cookie) -- then *I don't need your login name or password* because you've already provided your credentials!  Your bank trusts that the actions performed using the cookie were initiated by you -- not a malicious script from another site.

Comment: ... This class of attack is known as the [confused deputy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem), where software such as your browser is tricked into misusing its authority (in this case, an active session cookie with your bank).  At any rate, it's hard to say what the best approach is here.  Is this something for your own personal use, or is it something you intend to do on a public site?

Comment: OK, I see your point...
It's just for my personal use, so it doesn't have to be anything too fancy... I just need a way to login to a website in a session and submit a form (basically two POST requests).
I know a few languages etc, but I have never done anything like this before so I wouldn't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

You can only send cross-origin requests using [XHR](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) if both the [browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) and server support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Additionally, the third party site needs to allow your site to send such requests and to receive its responses. If it doesn’t, you aren’t allowed to send the request or receive its response respectively.